# SwiftUI: How can I align a view to a background image

Tags: swiftui

I have been trying to align a view to a background image, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for all devices. I am targeting iPhones in landscape orientation.

In this example I want to make the red rectangle align with the iMac screen. This code gets pretty close, by using an offset. It looks good in the preview canvas, but doesn't align in the Simulator or on a device.

I tried using .position(x:y:), but that was even more messy.

I found that if I crop the background so the target region is exactly centered, then it is possible, but I really hope that's not the only solution.

```
struct GeometryView: View {
    
    let backgroundImageSize = CGSize(width: 1500, height: 694)
    let frameSize = CGSize(width: 535, height: 304)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let widthScale = geometry.size.width / backgroundImageSize.width
            let heightScale = geometry.size.height / backgroundImageSize.height
            let scale = widthScale > heightScale ? widthScale : heightScale
            let frame = CGSize(width: frameSize.width * scale,
                               height: frameSize.height * scale)
            ZStack {
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
                    .foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.5)
                    .offset(x: 5, y: -8)
                
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            .background(
                Image("imac-on-desk")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea())
        }
    }
}
```

[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxeCN.png)

Comment: why are you using a ZStack & and a background modifier? Try to set the frame to the image not just the stack.

Comment: I'm new to SwiftUI and I'm learning from tutorials I find on the internet. This was just one of several ways I found to do it.

Answer (score 0):

this would work, but only on an iPhone 12. If you use `.scaledToFill` on the image the different display aspect ratios of phones will lead to different offsets. You could at least crop the background image , so the white screen is exactly in the center of the image.

```
var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.5)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2.45,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 2.1)
                .offset(x: -geometry.size.width * 0.025, y: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in my question. I found that if I center the target region exactly in my background, then it is possible, but I really hope that's not the only solution.